# Divide positive and negative elements with different numbers. Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a (8864,40) array A, containing both negative and positive values. I wanna divide the positive values of the array with the maximum value of A, and divide the negative values with the minimum of A. Is it possible to do this whilst also keeping the shape of the array A? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can use `np.where` for that.

Comment: Maximum value of the array will be positive and the minimum will be negative, in the end you will have only array with all positive values with maximum value 1. Is that what you want or you want to normalize the array so it has only values between -1 and 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?

```
np.where(A > 0, A/A.max(), A/A.min())
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that should solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

please see the snipped below

```
A[A > 0] /= np.max(A)
A[A < 0] /= np.min(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a list you can use list comprehension such as

```py
x = [-2, 1, 3, 0, -4, -1, 0, 5, 2]
y = [i / max(x) if i > 0 else i / abs(min(x)) for i in x]

print(x)
print(y)
```

that produces

```
[-2, 1, 3, 0, -4, -1, 0, 5, 2]
[-0.5, 0.2, 0.6, 0.0, -1.0, -0.25, 0.0, 1.0, 0.4]
```

where sign of the number `-` or `+` is conserved. Without the use of `abs()` you will get only positive values.

I do not quite understand by the phrase

> Is it possible to do this whilst also keeping the shape of the array A?

By any change the shape means the sign?

Comment: I tried this. But the array was not 1D. Thanks.